# gcc/clang: error: conflicting types for <function_name>: why function name matters?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, clang, diagnostics

Sample code (t987.c):

```
void *NAME();
void *NAME(void *, int, unsigned);
```

Invocation:

```
$ gcc t987.c -c -DNAME=memset1
<nothing>

$ gcc t987.c -c -DNAME=memset
<command-line>: error: conflicting types for ‘memset’; have ‘void *(void *, int,  unsigned int)’
t987.c:2:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘NAME’
    2 | void *NAME(void *, int, unsigned);
      |       ^~~~
<command-line>: note: previous declaration of ‘memset’ with type ‘void *(void *, int,  long unsigned int)’
t987.c:1:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘NAME’
    1 | void *NAME();

# clang: the same behavior
```

Question: why function name matters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no other definition or declaration for `memset1`.  So these two declarations are compatible:

```
void *memset1();
void *memset1(void *, int, unsigned);
```

Because the first one says the number and type of parameters is unknown.

This however gives you a problem:

```
void *memset();
void *memset(void *, int, unsigned);
```

Because `memset` is defined by the C standard and therefore considered part of the implementation, it is also internaly declared as:

```
void *memset(void *, int,  long unsigned int)
```

Which conflicts with your second declaration.